# Simulation of a DoS attack with Apache JMeter

Tags: jmeter

i want to use the tool Apache JMeter in order to make an http flood in a website that i have designed in Visual Studio 2017. My question is, if i start running the website and in the same time start the http flood, is it "safe" for my PC? I mean, is it possible to cause a damage because of the resource consumption? Or is it depended from the number of threads i'll use at the JMeter script parameters?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the hardware perspective I don't think you will be able to damage your machine as most probably it will [throttle](https://www.quora.com/What-is-CPU-throttling) or simply turn off when temperatures will exceed acceptable threshold.

From the test results point of view you might be getting inaccurate metrics especially if you run JMeter at the same machine as when it comes to high loads both JMeter and your website will become very resource intensive will "fight" for the resources like CPU, RAM, etc.

So I would recommend considering deploying your website on prod-like environment and use separate JMeter load generator(s) for conducting the load. This way you will get confidence that test results are not impacted by mutual interference.

If you cannot set up proper load testing environment unfortunately your test scenario will not make a lot of sense, [there are still some areas which you can test on a scaled-down environment from performance perspective](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-scaled-down-environment-part-two-five-things-you-can-test) like:

- integration test
- [soak test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing)
- interoperability test